Unable to clean Google Drive cache
I've been using Google Drive Desktop for a while due to its mirroring features and the convenience of accessing cloud files through Finder.
Recently, I set an entire directory to be available offline, not realizing its size was over 50 GB. Afterward, I reconfigured it to have those files available only online. However, the large cache created did not disappear even after quitting the app or rebooting my computer.
Unfortunately, there is no button to clear the cache, although some tutorials suggest this option was available in previous versions.
Is there a way to clear the cache without uninstalling the app or damaging the data stored in the cloud? Command-line operations are preferred over GUI methods.
Version: 94.0.1.0 (Silicon).

